# How to split items within one cell in a certain column and implement one-hot encoding?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a df, one of the column looks like this:

```
              channels  
0       [email, mobile, social]         
1  [web, email, mobile, social]         
2          [web, email, mobile]             
3          [web, email, mobile]             
4                  [web, email]            
5  [web, email, mobile, social]      
6  [web, email, mobile, social]         
7       [email, mobile, social]        
8  [web, email, mobile, social]            
9          [web, email, mobile]
```

How can I split each item in each cell so that I can implement one-hot encoding?

I tried:

```
portfolio.channels.str.split(expand=True)

Return:
      0
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   NaN
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

#create the MultiLabelBinarizer and fit_trasnform your data (only first 3 rows here)
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
a = mlb.fit_transform(df.channels.to_numpy())

#create the dataframe with columns names being the 
df_ohe = pd.DataFrame(a,df.index, mlb.classes_)

print (df_ohe)
   email  mobile  social  web
0      1       1       1    0
1      1       1       1    1
2      1       1       0    1
```

Comment: `MultiLabelBinarizer` is faster though.. IMO

Comment: @anky I guess the `explode` before unfortunately slow down the use of `OneHotEncoder` in this specific case :)

Comment: I've been messing around to try to figure out how to update my pandas package in SageMaker, no luck...so I'll be using 'MultiLabelBinarizer'

Answer (score 5):

You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the column and *then* apply one hot encoding. Here's an example using the first two rows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

print(df)
                        chanels
0       [email, mobile, social]
1  [web, email, mobile, social]

# explode column of lists
df_exploded = df.chanels.explode()
# input data to encode, it must be 2D hence the reshape
X = df_exploded.to_numpy()[:,None]
# fit and transform the one hot encoder
oh = OneHotEncoder()
oh.fit(X)
pd.DataFrame(oh.transform(X).todense(), columns=oh.get_feature_names())

   x0_email  x0_mobile  x0_social  x0_web
0       1.0        0.0        0.0     0.0
1       0.0        1.0        0.0     0.0
2       0.0        0.0        1.0     0.0
3       0.0        0.0        0.0     1.0
4       1.0        0.0        0.0     0.0
5       0.0        1.0        0.0     0.0
6       0.0        0.0        1.0     0.0
```

From here we could go back to the initial dataframe strucure by grouping by the exploded series' index, and adding as:

```
df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(oh.transform(X).todense(), 
                          columns=oh.get_feature_names())
df_encoded.groupby(df_exploded.index).sum()

   x0_email  x0_mobile  x0_social  x0_web
0       1.0        1.0        1.0     0.0
1       1.0        1.0        1.0     1.0
```

Comment: The first line gave me error ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'```

Comment: You need to update pandas then, its new in version 0.25.0 @Cecilia

Comment: hmm I see, I'm now using AWS SageMaker, I'll update it, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Solution from `pandas`

```
df['channels'].explode().str.get_dummies().sum(level=0)
```

Comment: Aparently I just forgot that `MultiLabelBinarizer` existed :) Nice one

Comment: @yatu I post later than Ben.T and change to pandas explode ~

Comment: Hi can you explain a little bit what's the purpose of '```sum(level=0)```', thanks.

Comment: My explode+OneHot seems pretty overkill having MultiLabelBinarizer, guess might be worth leaving too though. get_dummies is nice, though you lose the fit/transform utility.

Comment: @Cecilia str.get_dummies , will create dummies variable for each row, after we explode , we split one row into many, so we need combine them back ~

Comment: @yatu convert back can be down with `dot` ~ :-)